# how to get users information stored in several tables and show in his profile, is it posible with single query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have developed an online auction system in which users can sale or buy goods, my problem is with retrieving auctions relative information that are in two separate tables one contains information such as `(auction_id,owner,title,description,base_price,..)` and the other contains information about requests for each auction:     `(bid_id,auction_id,bidder,price,date)`, each user may post several auctions or not, `i want to show the highest price and the bidder(some one who gives such price) for that price and number of requests additional to information stored in auction table for each auction`
but when i join to table, if there is no request for auction so the result will be zero and you will see the message: there is no information to show but the user has just posted a new auction, what should i do?! should i check if there is a request for each auction and if yes then get these information?! dosent in code duplication? in this way i should connect to db twice in a single request for profile page
here is my tables and current query:

```
create table `auction`(
`auction_id`      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`owner`            VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL,
`group_id`         TINYINT      UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`title`            VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`sale_type`        VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
`base_price`       INT          NOT NULL,
`min_increase` INT NULL,
`photo`            VARCHAR(200) NULL,
`description`      VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
`start_date`       DATETIME     NOT NULL,
`termination_date` DATETIME     NULL,
`sold`             VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`purchaser`        VARCHAR(32)  NULL,
`deleted`          VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
FOREIGN KEY(owner)     REFERENCES users(user_name) on delete cascade on update cascade,
FOREIGN KEY(purchaser) REFERENCES users(user_name) on delete cascade on update cascade,
FOREIGN KEY(group_id)  REFERENCES commodity_groups(group_id) on delete cascade on update cascade)
ENGINE=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

create table `bid`(
`bid_id`      INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`auction_id`  INT  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`bidder`      VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`price`       INT         NOT NULL,
`date`        DATETIME    NOT NULL,
`deleted`     VARCHAR(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
FOREIGN KEY(auction_id) REFERENCES auction(auction_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(bidder) REFERENCES users(user_name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

and here is my query i use prepared statements:

```
SELECT `auction`.`auction_id` , `title` , `base_price` , `min_increase` , `photo` ,    `description` , `start_date` , `termination_date` , `max_bidder` , `bids_count` , `max_bid`
FROM `auction` , (

SELECT `bid`.`auction_id` , `bidder` AS max_bidder, `bids_count` , `max_bid`
FROM `bid` , (

SELECT `auction_id` , count( bid_id ) AS bids_count, max( price ) AS max_bid
FROM `bid`
WHERE `auction_id`
IN (

SELECT `auction_id`
FROM `auction`
WHERE `owner` = ?
)
GROUP BY (
auction_id
)
) AS temp
WHERE `bid`.`auction_id` = `temp`.`auction_id`
AND `price` = `max_bid`
) AS temp2
WHERE `auction`.`auction_id` = `temp2`.`auction_id`
```

it is clear that if there is no request for auction, the result will be zero and no auction will be shown to user in his profile, however he or she has just post a new auction, i will thank if any body could help me

Answer (score 2):

What you have is more of a database design problem and a future scalability problem than an actual problem. You know you can make two requests if you want to.

If you care about scaling things up, you're going to have to think very carefully about what user information you want to replicate across multiple servers, and how you're going to synchronize that. The basic answer is: Yes, you use joins to include the user information you want. But a more complicated answer is that you might want to create mini tables with just a little bit of user information (duplicated and synchronized) that you can join very quickly, which no user would ever write to -- in other words they are written only by the master table either through a slave setup or with some cron job.

A lot depends on how large you expect your site to be and how many people might be writing to the users table. It's assumed that many people will be writing to the auction table, so ideally you don't want ANY foreign key dependencies on that table or you will get deadlocks. It should be an ISAM or Federated table, probably.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you know im an Amateur and have no Experience, i didnt understood your mean really

Comment: do you mean that i have to create a table which would hold information like request count, max_price and max_bidder for each auction?